# Need Windows script to create folders named with file dates and move files to the matching folder

Tags: windows, powershell, file-management, sorting, file-search

I need a CMD or Powershell script or batch file to

- step through a list of files
- make a folder named with the date of a file if it doesn't already exist, then
- move that file into its matching folder.

I have a list of about 400 files like this:

[image]

Using this as an example, the script should create a folder including the top two files called `2018-05-16`, a folder with the 3 next files called `2018-05-17` etc. Preferably in the same folder as the files are located now.

I'm on Windows 8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample directory before

```
> gci

    Verzeichnis: A:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-05-16     16:02             14 GOPR0150.MP4
-a----       2018-05-16     16:10             14 GOPR0151.MP4
-a----       2018-05-17     01:25             14 GOPR0152.MP4
-a----       2018-05-17     01:32             14 GOPR0153.MP4
-a----       2018-05-17     01:32             14 GOPR0154.MP4
```

running this small PowerShell script

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\06\SU_1355955.ps
ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem '.\GOPR*.mp4')){
    $DestFolder = Join-Path $File.DirectoryName $File.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    if (!(Test-Path $DestFolder)){MD $DestFolder|Out-Null}
    $File | Move-Item -Destination $DestFolder
}
```

---

```
> gci -recurse -file

    Verzeichnis: A:\2018-05-16

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-05-16     16:02             14 GOPR0150.MP4
-a----       2018-05-16     16:10             14 GOPR0151.MP4

    Verzeichnis: A:\2018-05-17

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-05-17     01:25             14 GOPR0152.MP4
-a----       2018-05-17     01:32             14 GOPR0153.MP4
-a----       2018-05-17     01:32             14 GOPR0154.MP4
```

**Edit: depending on your local date format you may have to**
change to `.ToString('yyyy\-MM\-dd')`

Answer (score 0):

The script does not recognise the DestFolder, not sure what am I doing wrong. I have also changed the date format. running in command prompt I get the following

E:\Travel Videos\GOPRO\20221015>ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem '.\GOPR*.mp4')){
'ForEach' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\Travel Videos\GOPRO\20221015>    $DestFolder = Join-Path $File.DirectoryName $File.LastWriteTime.ToString('dd\MM\yyyy')
'$DestFolder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\Travel Videos\GOPRO\20221015>    if (!(Test-Path $DestFolder)){MD $DestFolder|Out-Null}
$DestFolder)){MD was unexpected at this time.

E:\Travel Videos\GOPRO\20221015>    $File | Move-Item -Destination $DestFolder
'$File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).